# How to properly use async functions in a loop in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, fs

My code takes a line and tries to get an MP3 from Google translate with the line.

However, the loop is too fast for the Async function `fs.exists(...)` and only the last line in the array is fetched. I'm guessing the loop is changing the variables `filename` and `line` before they are even being requested.

What's a good work around to this? I could see using `fs.existsSync(...)` as one possible solution, but is there a *better* one?

```
for (var i = 0, length = lines.length; i < length; i++) {
    // Get the line in question
    var line = lines[i].trim();

    // The saving filename
    var filename = crypto.createHash('md5').update(line).digest('hex') + ".mp3";

    // Does the file exist?
    fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
        console.log(line + "->" + filename);
        // We have to process it!
        if (!exists) {
            request
                .get({
                    'url': url,
                    'qs': {
                        'tl': lang,
                        'q': line,
                        'ie': 'UTF-8'
                    }
                })
                .on('error', function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                })
                .on('response', function(response) {
                    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                        console.error(response);
                    }
                })
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Don't define a function inside a loop. It's a classic JS error that gets people (like me) over and over again.

Comment: This will be less of an issue if environments support  [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). http://stackoverflow.com/a/16661498/218196